# What's the most efficient way to manually hold a specific speed?

Tags: fuel-consumption, cruise-control

I noticed that my new car is by activated cruise controll at lets say 50 km/h handling this speed by displaying an current consume of 1.8~2.4 l/100km,
while when I'm trying to find the required pressure to the peddal to keep the speed constant, I'm when I got there, at a consume of 2.2~2.9 l/100km.

Same for the high way: cruise controll: 3.9~4.9 l/100km at 120 km/h, while I get with the mentioned method at that speed 4.5~6.0 on average.

For speeding up 5 seconds to 125 and then falling back to 115 I have in the speeding up phase a consume of around 12 l/100km but it feels like I'm faster back on 115 then it takes me to speed up to 125 again, so making my consume even worse and also letting me asume its not a micro speed up followed by a micro moment of falling back what the cruise controll internally does.

But I noticed so far I don't feel comfortable with activating cruisecontroll in inner city, as it appears to me, this could let me get to break too late when its required. But I'd also like to optimize my consume in the city.

So in what way is the cruisecontroll algorithm probably controlling the engine for keeping the speed? Is this to be assumed the most efficent way? If not so what is the best patern to use my cars fuel most efficient when trying to keep a specific speed?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but the cruise control just increases the throttle whenever the speed starts dropping below the setpoint and decreases when it goes above. This is not necessarily most efficient. For example, going uphill is more efficient by speeding up before the climb and letting the speed drop a little while climbing instead of throttling hard on the incline (which is what the cruise control does, wastefully).

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing: But thats what I'm asking. So My assumption was wrong. But therefor the question remains: why the cruise controll does do this in a much more fficient way then I do and how could I get close to the same?

Comment: My guess would be that the cruise control is doing a better job at keeping the speed constant than you. The larger portion of your fuel consumption is acceleration. Keeping the speed is rather economical. If you maintain a speed for a longer time without braking and accelerating, you will inevitably get better mileage.

Comment: This question seems very much to me to be a driving technique question, which is off topic. I'm leaving it set for the mean time to see what the masses are thinking.

Comment: It is more considered as "How does an/my engine work regards consumption and whats the most efficient way to optimize its output" While I aggree this could be a break down to driving technique, its actually about the way the engine is working.

Comment: He's asking if constant speed (100kmph) is better than accelarting and decelerating. Get to 110kmph then coast to 90kmph and go back up to 110kmph (100kmph avg). While coasting does consume minimal fuel, accelerations are the bane of ICEs in terms of fuel economy.

Comment: Either I missed it or you neglected to mention which car this is (make/model/year). That will figure heavily into explaining what's going on.

Comment: If you're driving in automatic... 

The car might gear up(to the most efficient gear) when maintaining constant speed because it is expecting you to be going that speed for a while, vs. you driving yourself and the car keeping it in a lower gear because the car thinks that's the best place to be to be prepared for whatever you do next